# Data factory Copy Task - Using Stored Procedure containing temporary tables

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

In Data Factory we're using Copy Data task to move some data. The source is a SQL Stored Procedure and within the stored procedure some temp tables are being created. The Sink is an auto created physical SQL table (not a temp table).

When running the pipeline we get an error complaining about invalid object which is the temp table.

```
 Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Invalid object name `'#w_activity'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Invalid object name '#w_activity'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=208,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=0,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=208,State=0,Message=Invalid object name '#w_activity'.,},],'`
```

The same sproc executes perfectly via SSMS. Having done some digging it looks like one solution is to re write the stored procedure to use table variables instead of temp tables.

Can anyone explain if there is a way that temp tables can be retained so that we don't have to re write all our stored procs, or if not can anyone explain why they can't/won't work.  I understand about different sessions between the ADF activities, however these are being created/used within the same stored proc within a single activity.

Many Thanks

Comment: use a real table

Comment: SSIS used to have similar problems with getting metadata from stored procedures containing temp tables. You could try the "wacky" solution here if it is the same underlying cause. https://sites.google.com/site/alledocuments/sql/ssis-and-stored-procedures-using-temp-tables

Comment: we really don't want to have to change the the calling method for each sproc as its part of a metadriven ETL framework.  Looks like we'll either have to opt for the table variables or just use physical tables and drop them afterwards.  I don't understand the technical reason why temp tables can't be used though within the sproc.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your scenario and got the similar error.

[image]

Using stored procedures, global temporary tables (##T), a workaround for doing this is to write stored procedure for getting data from temp table and execute it will give you a result.

- Created stored procedure to fetch data from temp table.

```sql
 create proc testtemp as
 begin
 select * from ##test
 end
```

[image]

- Using that stored procedures in copy activity.[image]

**Successful execution**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeAuw.png]

Comment: that only works if the global temp table already exists. if you try and create/populate the global temp table within the stored proc and then select from it then you will get a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue, I had copied an existing copy activity, I found when I cleared the mappings it worked for me, without any changes to the stored proc